# Wix: Write register entries under HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I have a super simple installer to test if a installer can write register entries under HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node (the msi is target x86 and I'm testing it on a Win7 x64 machine).

The problem is: it just does not want to write anything under Wow6432Node at all. Following is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="f671ee4d-dd0a-4f7f-a4d1-1d181d2f3002" Name="TestWow" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="X" UpgradeCode="5d030587-0b6f-4a55-b090-c97a4fd22d13">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perUser" InstallPrivileges="limited"/>

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="XWix" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="TestWow" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir" />
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
      <Component Id="TestWow" Guid="f671ee4d-dd0a-4f7f-a4d1-1d181d2f3002">
        **<RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Classes\TestWow">
          <RegistryValue Name="Test" Value="Wow" Type="string" KeyPath="yes"/>
        </RegistryKey>**
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I've even tried to modify the registry part like:

```
<RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\TestWow">
  <RegistryValue Name="Test" Value="Wow" Type="string" KeyPath="yes"/>
</RegistryKey>
```

It still does not work.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think hkcu is virtualised in the same way as hklm. You need to ensure your component is marked as a 32 bit one and any virtualization will be taken care of for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this key using custom action. Dot NET Framework 4.0 has a special feature (**RegistryView**) to read the 64 bit registry from 32 bit applications.  Refer [this](http://www.rhyous.com/2011/01/24/how-read-the-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-application-or-vice-versa/) document for more information. You need to write another custom action to remove this key in uninstall.

Custom Action:

```
[CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
    {
        RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64);
        key = key.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Classes\Wow6432Node", true);
        key.CreateSubKey("TestWow").SetValue("Test", "Wow", RegistryValueKind.String);

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

WiX:

```
<Binary Id="TestWow" SourceFile="CustomAction\TestProject\TestProject\bin\Release\TestProject.CA.dll" />
<CustomAction Id="TESTWOW" BinaryKey="TestWow" DllEntry="CustomAction1" Return="check" />

<Custom Action="TESTWOW" After="InstallInitialize" >Not Installed</Custom>
```

Comment: I tested this approach and it is worked for me. Is there anything wrong in this approach? If so let me know, I will correct myself.