# How to copy binary registry value in WiX

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I need to copy a binary (REG_BINARY) registry value to a registry key under a Wow6432 Node.

The value is in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId

The WiX installer target is x86

The machine is 64bit

Windows 7 64 bit

Below is the part of my WiX script that attempts to do the copy. Note: @Win64=yes, which I assume will take the value from the NON-Wow6432Node. The result is an error message during installation

> Could not write value DigitalProductID to key ... verify that you have sufficient access to that key

```
 <Property Id="PROPERTYBINARY">
  <RegistrySearch Id='searchbinary'
                  Type='raw'
                  Win64='yes'
                  Root='HKLM'
                  Key='SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion'
                  Name='DigitalProductId'/>
 </Property>

  <Component Id="componentbinary" Guid="{04367CD7-B41A-4A1D-81C7-E24029FF4926}>
      <RegistryValue 
          Id='registrykeybinary' 
          Root='HKLM' 
          Key='Software\mycompany\myapp' 
          Type='binary' 
          Name='DigitalProductId' 
          Value="[PROPERTYBINARY]" 
          KeyPath='yes' 
          Action='write'/>
  </Component>
```

Copying a string (e.g. HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\CurrentType) works and creates the value under Wow6432Node, e.g.

```
<Property Id="PROPERTYSTRING">
  <RegistrySearch Id='searchstring'
                  Type='raw'
                  Win64='no'
                  Root='HKLM'
                  Key='SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion'
                  Name='CurrentType'/>
</Property>


  <Component Id="componentstring"  Guid='{F7231D06-DC3B-4D0F-BCBC-EDBD4DF38CA2}'>
      <RegistryValue Id='registrykeystring'
         Root='HKLM' 
         Key='Software\mycompany\myapp'  
         Type='string' Name='CurrentType' 
         Value="[PROPERTYSTRING]" 
         KeyPath='yes' 
         Action='write'/>
  </Component>
```

The registry export (of both the binary and string values) is:

```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\mycompany]

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\mycompany\myapp]
   "DigitalProductId"=hex:
   "CurrentType"="Multiprocessor Free"
```

( Alternatives I've tried: The same as above but using RegistryKey and RegistryValue

```
   <RegistryKey ...
          <RegistryValue
```

)

My question is the sames as this one [Reading and writing to x86 and x64 registry keys from the same application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424205/reading-and-writing-to-x86-and-x64-registry-keys-from-the-same-application) but instead of doing it in C# I'm using WiX. Perhaps I need a custom action as in this post [Wix: Write register entries under HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504395/wix-write-register-entries-under-hkcu-software-classes-wow6432node?rq=1) ?

Answer (score 0):

As already *answered* in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504395/wix-write-register-entries-under-hkcu-software-classes-wow6432node?rq=1) I managed to get this working by

1. Creating a custom action (C#).
2. Calling the custom action during InstallExecuteSequence.

For an understanding of the real problem, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424205/reading-and-writing-to-x86-and-x64-registry-keys-from-the-same-application) helped. When the installer runs on a 64bit machine as a 32bit app, then the 64bit registry is not visible only the Wow6332Node (and all the common entries). The custom action can access the 64bit part of the registry using

```
 RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser,RegistryView.Registry64);
 key = key.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Classes\Wow6432Node", true);
```